# Using Replace function in sample with R

Tags: r, sample-data

I'm trying to use sample function however encounturing some trouble.
My objective is to have 500 samples from a normal distrubition and replace any numbers that are less than 5.
I tried using replace function but not familiar with syntax and keep recieivng errors.

My normal distrubition code is:

```
 x <- rnorm(1000,10,4)
```

Comment: Would you mind to share the `replace` code that you've tried?

Comment: sample(x, size=500, replace = x<5)

Comment: Aha, ok, the `replace=` argument of the `sample` function is actually logical `TRUE/FALSE` where you can choose if the values are sampled only once or multiple occurences (=replacement).

Comment: May I ask with what you intend to replace the values `x < 5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove values smaller than 5 from `x` and then sample 500 values

```
sample(x[x > 5], 500)
```

Answer (score 2):

So it seems like you actually want a truncated normal distribution. I would suggest [`truncdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncdist/index.html). Then you can do

```r
library(truncdist)
set.seed(123)
x <- rtrunc(1000, "norm", a = 5, mean = 10, sd = 4)
```

to get the samples you want:

```r
summary(x)

#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  5.009   8.268  10.440  10.780  13.002  23.091 

plot(density(x, from = 5))
```

[image]